# Could a Necron be reprogrammed?

Tags: warhammer-40k, souls

In the WH40k universe, Necrons were once Necron'tyr who sold their soul's to C'tan an ancient god. He put them into living metal bodies so they could live forever.

However, what I'm not clear on is if they are robots that can be reprogammed, or if they have a 'soul' as such and the 'programming' goes much deeper?

*n.b* I'm well aware of the background and history of the Necron'tyr, I've poured over long, wordy wikia articles on Lexicanum, various forums and I've even resorted to d4chan, but I've not managed to digest the information down into something succinct and useful; a yes or no with some explanation.

Comment: I heard the Necron background has radically changed in 40K 6th Edition, including big changes to their relationship to the C'tan and to the nature of their "free will". Heard anything about it?

Comment: @AndresF no, but that would be integral to any answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Summary:**

**The [Necrons](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Necrons) as they exist today (in the 41 Millennium, of course) are not robots as we understand them, so they were not programmed in the classic sense.**

They are the product of merging nanotechnological materials (called 'living metal' by the Necron'tyr) with the spiritual and mental essence of the formerly living Necron'tyr using the vast psionic powers of their former masters, the extra-dimensional C'tan. They are basically a sentient species whose minds were transposed into machinery designed to enslave them. It is not likely their minds could be reprogrammed and since their bodies are very hard to kill, it would be a risky undertaking to bring Necron bodies anywhere in an effort to try.

Comment: And those Necrons with free will are the Necron Lords, so even if they could be be reprogrammed, it would be much, _much_ more dangerous to try!

Comment: @Thaddeus There is much whining from 40K players (not surprised, are you?) about the Necron "fluff" having changed in 6th Edition. Apparently, they are no longer robots without free will, and no longer the slaves of the C'tan (and actually, the C'tan are enslaved to the Necrons, or something of the sort). Heard anything about it? In true GW fashion, they have re-written the fluff :P (details might not be accurate in this comment, though)

Comment: Ensuing meta discussion: [What should we do about Wikipedia-like answers?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/2200#2200)

Comment: Yes, I saw the complaints. I reduced it to a single paragraph. I strive for complete answers but I recognize my style is not the preferred one. I have been trying to keep my answers short when it is at all possible. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Thaddeus thank you. So long as we can find a happy medium, I will be happy. Clearly your style doesn't suit everyone, but at times it might be useful. Would you be able to weigh in on the meta topic? Id like to hear all opinions.

Comment: IIRC aren't some of the Adeptus Mechanicus's special rules the result of using hacking programs for electronic warfare? I think that's how some of their stealth stuff works in-universe. The relevant game rules seem to apply as much to the Necrons as anyone else, so the Necrons are clearly vulnerable to hacking to some extent. I think that this answer was written before the AdMech were released as a faction, so maybe it could be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Ish. The Necron's minds are stated to be Engram copies of their originals (often degraded by the biotransference). But since the Necron's themselves have created ones for certain members of their species that were dead before biotransference, it should be possible. It's unlikely that the imperium could. But certain Necrons can override others (Trazyn does it all the time), and certain Necrons have experimented with biotransference on humans (use to be what gave the Pariahs, though now I believe it tends to just create unstable monstrosities).
At least as of the current lore that I've seen, heard, or read.

Side note, the fluff changed quite a bit. They now enslave the C'tan, but were originally enslaved to them (if I recall correctly the Silent King had the ability to get rid of the programs that allowed them to be directly controlled and enslaved by him and the C'Tan (which is why he now needs to get the Pharons and such to follow him willingly)). THe Flayed Ones also changed to it being a contagious curse from a destroyed C'tan instead of them waking up either to early or wrong.

ETA: To be clear, the Necrons now have absolutely no souls (The C'Tan ate them during the original biotransference). The Silent King and Trazyn (I think) both are mentioned as feeling wrong afterwards and realizing that they and the whole race had lost them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to cite your sources. Adding relevant quotes from the sources as well would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It is impossible to reprogram a Necron- they are the combination of a Necrontyr (NOT Necron'tyr) mind and a shell of necrodermis. The lower ranks (Canoptek constructs and Warriors) are mindless automatons, who serve the higher ranks without a second thought. AS we move further up the line, we see things like Immortals, Lychguard, and Praetorians- all of which have some semblance of free will, but are still required to offer fealty to the ranking noble on the theater of war. As for attempting to reprogram one of the Nobles...I'm not sure how you'd get remotely close to one without being disintegrated, stabbed, cut into multiple pieces, or, if you're a Space Marine, having your right hand chopped off then being shoved off a cliff by the phaeron (like pharaoh) of the Sautekh Dynasty.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer is nicely categorical, but it could use some citations if you can dog them up. But if the Warriors are truly mindless, why couldn't they be (re)programmed?

Comment: Without references, this seems opinion based.